# Is there a way to store the XMLStreamReader values temporarily within another XMLStreamReader for validations?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, stax, xmlstreamreader

I am not sure if this is possible so anyways thought of asking and getting clarified as I was unable to find anything similar to this here even after a lot of searches and trying out things. Really sorry if found a duplicate.

I am trying to parse the XML file using the `XMLStreamReader`. After reading I have to make few checks for my `localpart` based on which I need to assign this `XMLStreamReader` to different classes.

When I am making few checks I need to check the `current localpart` as well as `next localpart`. When I try to check the `next localpart` I am advancing to `next` element on `XMLStreamReader`. So I am trying to store the `current XMLStreamReader` within another `temp XMLStreamReader` but after the assignment when I try to navigate to next on the `current XMLStreamReader` then even the `temp XMLStreamReader` is changing I guess due to which I am unable to perform some of the action. Mainly I would like to perform `JAXB Unmarshalling` during which it's failing as its unable to get all the elements of the class.

I am aware the `XMLEventReader` has `peek()` but that is also failing so I am trying to store the `current XMLStreamReader` but its also not working and I read that its not most memory efficient. As my XML file can be very large I am trying to use the `XMLStreamReader`.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.xml");
        final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(xmlStream);
        //final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("io.model.jaxb");
        //final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        
        //Navigate to next and start of the XML Elements
        xmlStreamReader.next();
        
        //Read Until the end of the file
        while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
            
            //Check if the current `XML Tag` is "extension"
            if (xmlStreamReader.isStartElement() && xmlStreamReader.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("extension")) {
                
                //Create a tempStream to store the current stream values
                //final XMLStreamReader streamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader((InputStream) xmlStreamReader);
                final XMLStreamReader tempReader = xmlStreamReader;
                xmlStreamReader.next();
                
                //If the next element is "nextextension"
                if (xmlStreamReader.isStartElement() && xmlStreamReader.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("nextextension")) {
                    System.out.println("Double Extension Assign to CLASS C with both extension tag");
                    //final C cInfo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader, C.class).getValue();
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Single Extension Assign to CLASS B with single extension tag");
                    //final B cInfo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader, B.class).getValue();
                }
                
            }
            
            //Move to the next
            xmlStreamReader.next();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I was able to explain the issue. All I want to know if there is a way to achieve any of the below:

1. Temporarily store the `current XMLStreamReader` in another `temp XMLStreamReader` so that it can be used later.
2. If there is any other way to `peek()` into the `next localpart` within `XMLStreamReader`.

It would be really nice to get some inputs from experts here as I am stuck in this issue since yesterday.

Comment: which version of Java are you using? I don't think this has changed for ages (since v8?) but it's always better to be clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and response. I am using the latest `JDK 15`. Actually, after trying a lot and researching I was able to do this using the `MutableXMLStreamBuffer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer as it can be useful to someone in the future. After trying a lot and researching I found we can store the stream in `MutableXMLStreamBuffer`.

```
//Store the XMLStreamReader values within the buffer
final MutableXMLStreamBuffer buffer = new MutableXMLStreamBuffer();
buffer.createFromXMLStreamReader(xmlStreamReader);
```

Then you can access the same using following:

```
buffer.readAsXMLStreamReader()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution ! Be aware the class `MutableXMLStreamBuffer`is located in Sun packages. Using it may make your code not fully portable (when running with another JDK)

Comment: @TacheDeChoco ah I was not aware of it. Sure, I will look into this before the deployment. Thanks for brining into my notice.